# In ui-router, is it possible to have nested views within nested views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am doing my routing with ui-router and have a nested view that loads up some menu options for the item that is selected. My question is, is it possible to have nested views within a nested view with ui-router?

The code here works:

```
.state('settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: './templates/settings.html',
            controller: 'settingsCtrl'
        },
        'details@settings': {
           templateUrl: './templates/details.html',
           controller: 'detailCtrl' 
        }
    }
})
```

But say I wanted to load something attached to the details@settings view. How would I go about that? I have tried

```
.state('settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: './templates/main/settings.html',
            controller: 'settingsCtrl'
        },
        'detail@settings': {
            url: '',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: './templates/detail.html',
                    controller: 'detailCtrl'                            
                },
                'contact@detail@settings': {
                    templateUrl: './templates/contactpref.html'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I don't get any errors in the console on this, but it does break my original nested view. From what I have found the docs aren't really clear on if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Check the: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

and section **`views`**:

> an optional **`map<string, object>`** which defined multiple views, or targets views manually/explicitly.
>
> Examples:
>
> Targets three named ui-views in the parent state's template

```
views: {
  header: {
    controller: "headerCtrl",
    templateUrl: "header.html"
  }, body: {
    controller: "bodyCtrl",
    templateUrl: "body.html"
  }, footer: {
    controller: "footCtrl",
    templateUrl: "footer.html"
  }
}
```

That is it. That's what UI-Router will see and resolve for us. And why are not you provided with any error?

Because expect value of the `map<string, object>` is **`object`**. It is iterated for known properties *(`controller`, `templateUrl`)* - **and any uknown is ignored, not used, not found... skipped**

Solution:

After some experience with `UI-Router` I would suggest:

- if there are some features related - place them in state
- if there are some more features related, but only with some conditions - place them into child state.

That structure will bring many benefits, mostly: stable parent (not reloading always) and dynamic child - placing new and new content into some targets/anchors/ui-views whenever parameter is changed. Check:

- [Trying to have one subview call another subview using ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28016057/1679310)